Unsure how to solve Pychess daily puzzle (9/19/24, Chennis)
This is today's chess variant puzzle on Pychess:

The goal of this puzzle is to find a mate in 2 with White to move in the chess variant Chennis, which is a game created by Couch Tomato in 2021 which was designed primarily as a variant of Kyoto Shogi. A more in-depth explanation can be found here.
Also, for clarity, I will act like this is playing from position (since Pychess hides past moves to avoid people just plugging the game into analysis).

My thinking

Noticing the Cannon and Bishop on the 5th rank, this appears to be a puzzle where I either need to force Black's King onto the aforementioned rank, into White's "court" (an illegal move), or onto the "sidelines" (a & g files, also illegal).

We can actually narrow this down to either forcing Black into the 5th rank or into White's court because since this puzzle (#awr5p) is supposed to be a mate in 2, and forcing Black's king into the sidelines would probably take much longer than that.


Also, the checkmate sequence cannot begin with a rook move (since it will turn into a pawn afterwards). If White plays a rook move other than 1. Rg3=P, then Black can respond with 1. ...B@g3+ 2. Kf1 Fe2=C and now White cannot move their king without getting checkmated right afterwards.

If White plays 1. Rg3=P, the same sequence of moves happens, just with Black now playing 1. B@f2+ instead.



So this must mean that the Knight/Mayor is involved.

White must play either 1. Mc6=N+ or 1. Me6=N+ because this now forces Black to play 1. ...Ke4.

However, this is where I'm kind of stuck. Because now if White plays 1. Mc6=N+ Ke4 2. Nd4=M+, Black can retaliate with 2. ...Mxd4=N, and if White plays 1. Me6=N+ Ke4 2.Nf4=M+, Black can retaliate with 2. ...Mxd6=N.



So my question is: What is the solution here? I'm kind of confused about what to do here.
